# openstack compute service list --service nova-compute empty

Tags: openstack-nova

After the installation of nova-compute on compute node, it failed to start and this command from the controller node return an empty result
openstack compute service list --service nova-compute

And the nova-compute.log file contain these two messages:

018-11-19 12:06:05.446 986 INFO os_vif [-] Loaded VIF plugins: ovs, linux_bridge

2018-11-19 12:30:13.784 1140 INFO os_vif [-] Loaded VIF plugins: ovs, linux_bridge
openstack compute service list :

return three service components for the controller with a down state

+----+------------------+------------+----------+---------+-------+----------------------------+

| ID | Binary | Host | Zone | Status | State | Updated At

+----+------------------+------------+----------+---------+-------+----------------------------+

| 2 | nova-conductor | Controller | internal | enabled | down | 2018-11-17T17:32:48.000000 |

| 4 | nova-scheduler | Controller | internal | enabled | down | 2018-11-17T17:32:49.000000 |

| 5 | nova-consoleauth | Controller | internal | enabled | down | None

+----+------------------+------------+----------+---------+-------+----------------------------+
service nova-compute status :

Active

How can i resolve these problems ?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you might have missed to create the databases for nova_cell0.

```
# mysql -u root -p

MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE DATABASE nova_cell0;


MariaDB [(none)]> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON nova_cell0.* TO 'nova'@'localhost' \   IDENTIFIED BY 'NOVA_DBPASS';
 MariaDB [(none)]> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON nova_cell0.* TO 'nova'@'%' \   IDENTIFIED BY 'NOVA_DBPASS';

#su -s /bin/sh -c "nova-manage cell_v2 map_cell0" nova
# su -s /bin/sh -c "nova-manage cell_v2 create_cell --name=cell1 --verbose" nova
109e1d4b-536a-40d0-83c6-5f121b82b650
# su -s /bin/sh -c "nova-manage db sync" nova
# nova-manage cell_v2 list_cells
#su -s /bin/sh -c "nova-manage api_db sync" nova
```

make sure in /etc/nova/nova.conf in compute node you have added following configuration:

```
[DEFAULT]

enabled_apis = osapi_compute,metadata
transport_url = rabbit://openstack:RABBIT_PASS@controller
```

Then restart compute services.
the try the command `openstack compute service list.`

this solution also holds good when openstack compute service list is empty or nova hypervisor list is empty.